# How to trigger script once?

Tags: python, logic-bricks

How can i limit the script trigger to once per pulse ex. i want to  sub  1 from INT from OBJ  once when BOOL is true and RAY(sensor) is generating true pulse(with OBJ detected via RAY).It just keeps subtracting 1 from INT every tick. I tried to give RAY false pulse mode, but when RAY is detecting OBJ and after 1 sec BOOL becomes True ,it wont work.

Comment: Could you clarify the question a little? as it is written now It is hard to tell what you need.

Comment: i need to make my script trigger only once (not repeating all the time) until next true pulse

Comment: @terrio does the script keeps running when connected to the Ray sensor (with default settings) ?

Comment: it keeps running when the BOOL is true for sec with Ray connected, and i want to make it run only once untill bool becomes true again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added another variable  to save the state and toggle it every time, 'Done' indicates whether you have subtracted or not during this pulse :

```
def main():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner
    Ray = cont.sensors["Ray"]
    Bool = own["Bool"]
    Done = own["Done"]

    if Ray.positive and Bool and not Done:

        own["Done"] = True
        print("have nothing to do") 
    elif not Bool :
        own["Done"] = False

main()
```